# How can i set same title for all actions/views of a controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, title

All actions/views will have same title.

Like=>

```
<?php $this->set('title_for_layout', 'mysite'); ?>
```

How can I set this title for all actions/views in CakePHP ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want your site's name to appear on every page; I would simply set it manually in your layout:

`<title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?> - My Site Name</title>`

that way you can have a dynamic title, and have your site's name appear in the `<title>` of the page.

If you don't want this, you could set the value in a `beforeFilter` in your `app_controller.php`:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'My Site');
}
```

This will give every action/view the title `My Site`, and you can overwrite this on a per controller/action basis if needed.

Your page title should really be unique for every page however (generally); so unless you have a reason for having the same title I would consider otherwise.

Comment: see my comment about beforeRender() in the other answer

Comment: Using `beforeRender` will overwrite anything the user sets in the method. By using `beforeFilter`, you can overwrite the value if required in the method.

Comment: good point. but you can also make it work with beforeRender if you do not directly pass it on but save it in a variable in the controller. if === null then DEFAULT etc. then it is not invoked every time there is no view to render (before redirects etc)

Comment: should put that as an answer so I can +1!

Comment: well, after consideration your approach is fine, too. the overhead is so minimal that it would not even be noticed :)

Comment: @Ross, What do you mean by dynamic title ? I have already this in layout.ctp=> <title><?php echo $title_for_layout;?></title>

Comment: By "dynamic title" I mean that if you want your site name to appear on every page **in addition** to a unique title (e.g. `About Us - My Site`) as is quite common, then my first example allows this. By setting `Site Name` in the layout; you don't need to type it every time and can just focus on the "page title", if you like. The other code demonstrates how you can apply a global title to all of your actions/views in one location, with the ability to override as needed. Not sure how to clarify further

Answer (score 1):

In a controller you can set:

function beforeFilter()
 {

$this->pageTitle = "my page title";

parent::beforeFilter();
 }

Answer (score 1):

In your app controller set it in the `beforeFilter()` callback function

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->set('title_for_layout','Your title');
    }
}
```

Comment: again - not beforeFilter, but beforeRender!

Comment: What's the problem with beforeFilter ?